# Can someone solve this Code Blocks?

Tags: c, scanf

Solve this for me because I don't really know

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char ans;

    printf("1. The patients felt _____ after taking the medicine.\n");
    printf("\t a. best\n\t b. better\n\t c. good\n\n");
    scanf("%c", &ans);

    if (ans == 'b') {
        printf("2. I ______ my essay by the time the bell rings.\n");
        printf("\t a. have done\n\t b. shall do\n\t c. shall have done\n\n");
        scanf("%c", &ans);
    } else {
        printf("YOU FAILED!");
    };
    return 0;
}
```

If you answer the first question you proceed to next and answer the 2nd question, but the problem is I can't type the answer even though there's `scanf`.

Comment: Remove your semi-colon after your else braces and then try to run and i am able to run your code properly and gave answer too , try again to run

Comment: Update your Query with proper title ..

Comment: Do not change the code in the question, add to the question with an **EDIT** paragraph,  Modifying the question makes the comments and answers inconsistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char ans;

    printf("1. The patients felt _____ after taking the medicine.\n");
    printf("\t a. best\n\t b. better\n\t c. good\n\n");
    scanf("%c", &ans);

    if (ans == 'b') {
        printf("2. I ______ my essay by the time the bell rings.\n");
        printf("\t a. have done\n\t b. shall do\n\t c. shall have done\n\n");
        scanf(" %c", &ans);
    } else {
        printf("YOU FAILED!");
    };

    return 0;
}
```

The difference is:

```
scanf(" %c",&ans);
       ^ this space this will read whitespace characters (which newline also is)
         until it finds a non space character.
```

`scanf` did not consume the `\n` character that stayed in the buffer from the first `scanf` call.

I try this, and it works!

Comment: If the answer help you, you should accept the answer, with this way http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work to help future people that have the same question. You don't accept the answer, and maybe you are new here

Comment: Yeah i am new. Anyway tnx

Comment: No problem :) Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

The second `scanf("%c"...)` reads the linefeed that the first scanf left pending in standard input.  You can fix this by reading an extra character this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char ans;

    printf("1. The patients felt _____ after taking the medicine.\n");
    printf("\t a. best\n\t b. better\n\t c. good\n\n");
    scanf("%c%*c", &ans);

    if (ans == 'b') {
        printf("2. I ______ my essay by the time the bell rings.\n");
        printf("\t a. have done\n\t b. shall do\n\t c. shall have done\n\n");
        scanf("%c%*c", &ans);
    } else {
        printf("YOU FAILED!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`scanf("%c%*c", &ans)` reads a character and stores it into the `ans` variable, then it reads another character and discards it.  This way the `\n` typed by the user after the `b` is discarded.

An alternative is to ignore white space characters with `scanf(" %c", &ans)`: the  in the `scanf` format instructs `scanf` to read and ignore any whitespace characters.  The advantage of the first approach is that no characters are left pending after the `scanf` if the user entered a single character followed by enter, the second approach would leave the `\n` pending, but it would be ignored by the following `scanf`.